# Is there a way to write/delete on xml file without DOM?

Tags: php, xml, dom

I'm trying to write on xml file.
but my server have DOM as disabled.
so i can't use the DOM function.

is there a way to write on xml other then DOM?

**Files:**

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<events>
<record>
<event>aaa</event>
<eventDate>bbb</eventDate>
<desc>ccc</desc>
</record>
```

parser.php:

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

$record = array(
    'event' => $_POST['event'],
    'eventDate' => $_POST['eventDate'],
    'desc' => $_POST['desc'],
);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'calendar.xml' );

$doc->formatOutput = true;
$r = $doc->getElementsByTagName("events")->item(0);

$b = $doc->createElement("record");

$event = $doc->createElement("event");
$event->appendChild(
    $doc->createTextNode( $record["event"] )
);
$b->appendChild( $event );

$eventDate = $doc->createElement("eventDate");
$eventDate->appendChild(
    $doc->createTextNode( $record["eventDate"] )
);
$b->appendChild( $eventDate );

$desc = $doc->createElement("desc");
$desc->appendChild(
    $doc->createTextNode( $record["desc"] )
);

$b->appendChild( $desc );
$r->insertBefore( $b,$r->firstChild );

$doc->save("calendar.xml");

header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
```

what can i do?

Comment: DOM is enabled by default in PHP5. If your host disabled it, ask them why because there is no reason to do so. Better yet, switch providers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using PHP5 you can use [SimpleXML](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the file as if it were a plain text file. However, you will need to make sure all elements are closed and all data is escaped correctly. If you only need to output XML this is doable, but to write a parser that can add to and modify existing XML data is a tough job. Better try to enable DOM or find an out of the box library.